# Xterm and User problem on Linux From Scratch

Tags: users, xterm, lfs

I made a linux system using LFS book 7.8 and then went to BLFS 7.8. I installed lxdm and xfce4 desktop. All the necessary drivers and libraries are installed.

Now when I log in as root, I get no problem.

But when I log in as lfs (an unprivileged user) I get some weird problems

1. Xterm takes a looooong time to start (about 3 minutes)
2. The button at the top right corner, which shows the user name isn't visible after login, but shows up after 5 minutes or so
3. the button also responds after a long time
4. Also choosing shut down as root doesn't shut down the machine and greets me with the login screen

Comment: Does `xhost +127.0.0.1` help? Alternatively, if not, try then `xhost +` (and close 6000 port with iptables)

Comment: @siblynx I used xhost +127.0.0.1 and it worked for a little. But after rebooting the problem came up again. And could you elaborate a little on the command to close port 6000?

Comment: If `xhost +127.0.0.1` is working for you then you do not need to worry about 6000 port (although you still need to close it if the X server listens on it and you have a permissive firewall setup). About disappearing effect after reboot: you need to add this command just before your UI starts up. An old and conventional way is to add this command to the file named `.xinitrc` in your home directory, but now it's not probably working anymore because of complex desktop environments do they own fragmented ways of starting up programs. Seek your environment help files for startup programs first.

Comment: Maybe something is making a DNS request. It's not obvious to me what or why though. Run `strace -o xterm.strace -s9999 -T xterm -e /bin/true` and post the resulting trace file.

Comment: @Gilles here it is  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jz129orm64ykfxi/xterm.strace?dl=0

Comment: @AniketBhattacharyea So that didn't take several minutes, according to the trace. Is it the case that `xterm -e true` is instantaneous, but `xterm -e bash` isn't? If you run `bash -x` in a terminal, how long does it take? If running bash is the problem, post the content of your `.bashrc` and the trace of `bash -x` and tell us where in that trace it pauses.

Comment: @Gilles running `bash -x` is instantaneous . No problem with that one

Comment: @AniketBhattacharyea But did `strace -o xterm.strace -s9999 -T xterm -e /bin/true` take several minutes? According to the trace, the total time spent in syscalls is about 0.34s.

Comment: @Gilles no. It didn't take a long time

Comment: So can you please run that `strace` command on something that takes a long time? I'm trying to figure out *where* that time is being spent, and `strace -T` is likely to reveal that (it shows all system calls, and for each the time spent in that system call).